# How could a Hindu God commit a sin?

Tags: brahma

How come God's Make sins like in the case of Brahma who lied to Shiva & who had lust for the beautiful woman he created?

Comment: A metaphysical idea always underlies such allegories. One should be able to read between the lines to get a grasp beyond the surface level which is in figurative language.(Creator Brahma is considered the highest jiva-tattva,and not Parabrahman)

Comment: Yes what Athrey ji has told is right. I have also rarely heard someone saying that Brahma ji is God or Parabrahman. He is also a Jivaa and has a definite lifespan.